# Why is my object moving faultily in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

In my program, I am trying to move my cuboid using my arrow keys. However, it moves but sort of leaves behind replicas of itself. I am trying to move the health bar above it too. This is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,242,0)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)

size = winHeight,winWidth = (1350,668)

pygame.key.set_repeat(50,50)
x,y = 625,490

towerHealth = 1450
healthAdjusted = towerHealth / 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Stormtroopers")
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP: y -= 5
            if event.key == K_DOWN: y += 5
            if event.key == K_LEFT: x -= 5
            if event.key == K_RIGHT: x += 5

    tower = [
             pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,(x,y,100,160)),
             pygame.draw.rect(screen,darkBlue,(x,y,100,160),5),
             pygame.draw.polygon(screen,blue,((x,y),(x + 50,y - 50),(x + 150,y - 50),(x + 100,y))),
             pygame.draw.polygon(screen,darkBlue,((x,y),(x + 50,y - 50),(x + 150,y - 50),(x + 100,y)),5),
             pygame.draw.polygon(screen,darkBlue,((x + 100,y),(x + 150,y - 50),(x + 150,y + 110),(x + 100,y + 160)))
             ]

    healthBar = [
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,(x,y - 80,150,15),5),
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,(x + 3,y - 77,healthAdjusted,10))
                ]

    if towerHealth <= 0:
        gameExit = True

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to erase the old position of the cuboid by drawing the background over it, otherwise you'll end up seeing two copies. Pygame does not automatically erase everything you've drawn with every update, you have to do that yourself. [Here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html) is a tutorial. You may also want to check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705361/pygame-display-update-does-not-clear-blit-image) on stackoverflow.